# Refresh page using echo with variable

Tags: php, html, refresh

I'm using the following piece of code to refresh the page after a few query's have been carried out:

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh //CONTENT="0; URL=editeventstaff.php?id=".$_POST[id]."">';
```

The current url contains an 'id' variable passed from the pervious page. Therefore when the page refreshes the url needs to contain this variable.

The id is stored in `$_POST[id]`.

How can I make this work? At the moment the page is refreshing to `editeventstaff.php?id=` (without the id value).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh //CONTENT="0; URL=editeventstaff.php?id="'.$_POST[id].'">';
```